# How to pass through only vertical pan touches on top view to view underneath

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

There are a number of other S/O questions that discuss passing touches through a view on top to the view underneath. This is achievable by overriding the `hitTest(_:with:)` and/or `point(inside:with:)` functions of `UIView`.

In my case, the view underneath is a vertical scroll view partially obscured by the view above it. These two views are siblings, that is to say that neither of these two views are a subview of the other, but both have the same superview. The top view contains interactable subviews such as buttons and a horizontally-scrolling collection view.

**I want vertical pan gestures on the top view, and *ONLY* vertical pan gestures, to pass through to the scroll view underneath. All other touch types on the top view should be received by the top view and its subviews as normal.**

One way to partially achieve this is to override `hitTest(_:with:)` for the top view to have it only pass hits to its subviews, like buttons and the horizontal collection view, and not itself.

```
class TopView: UIView {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {        
        let superHitTest = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        return (superHitTest === self) ? nil : superHitTest
    }

}
```

The problem with this solution is that vertical pan gestures that begin on any of these subviews will not be passed to the scroll view underneath. This creates some awkward dead-zones when the user tries to pan vertically.

Alternatively, I can almost get what I want by overriding `point(inside:with:)` and then adding gesture recognizers, such as `UITapGestureRecognizer`, to handle specific touches on the top view.

```
class TopView: UIView {

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {        
        return false
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.tapGestureRecognizer = tapGestureRecognizer
    }

    @objc func onTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // custom hit test logic
    }

}
```

This mechanism is also less than perfect, as it becomes more complicated handling things like horizontal panning for the aforementioned collection view, etc.... I think it might be possible but I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: You say you want **vertical only** ... is your scroll view content wide enough that you have vertical ***and horizontal*** scrolling when interacting directly with the scroll view? But you want gestures in the "overlay view" to only scroll the scroll view vertically? And... does your "overlay view" extend outside the frame of the scroll view?

Comment: @DonMag good questions! I simplified it in my OP but actually the scroll view underneath is a horizontally-paging scroll view containing two full-width vertically-scrolling collection views side-by-side. Each collection view has the same size as the horizontal scroll view's visible size. The overlay view frame is fully contained within the horizontal scroll view's frame, and has the same width as both of the collection views. Hence, I would like vertical pans on the overlay view to scroll the visible collection view, but horizontal pans should not be passed through.

Comment: I've come up with two more possible solutions that I am trying now, and I'll update the OP with my findings.

Comment: Hmmm... If your other possible solutions don't work - I may have a *potential* solution for you, but the fact that you have side-by-side vertically scrolling collection views in a horizontally-paged collection view complicates things a bit.

Comment: @DonMag the full context of what I'm trying to achieve is essentially just a shared header for both collection views. I want the two side-by-side collection views to have one shared header view, such that the header remains stationary when swiping left/right between the collection views. I've tried a couple other hacks now that have gotten close to what I want but haven't quite solved it yet. Wishing I could just pass gesture recognizer touches from the top view programmatically to the visible collection view's pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: Actually I think I might have figured this out...was thinking about it the wrong way. I had been trying to add a new pan gesture recognizer to the view but what I needed was to add the collections view's built in gesture recognizer to the view. After I test more to make sure it does indeed work I will post an answer with details.